# Install Processing on a Windows 11 machine?

Tags: windows, processing

I've just tried installing Processing (4.0 Beta 5) on two Windows 11 machines. In each case, Windows Defender declared that a virus was found and the program wouldn't run. Can anyone help me understand this and run Processing?

Thanks.

Comment: You may have more help on the Processing forums for this kind of question. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

This is easily fixable. First, temporarily shut off Windows Defender. Complete the installation. Re-enable it. Done :) Good luck with Processing!

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer! I'll give it a try.